# Sonar Buildbreaker Skip Failing the Build

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube

I am using Jenkins job to build .Net project. I have added sonar analysis.

D:\Temp\tools\Scanner_MSBuild-2.2\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:myproj /n:myproj-full /v:1.0.0 /s:D:\Temp\SonarQube.Analysis.xml

I have updated "SonarQube.Analysis.xml" with required sonar url and login credentials. But it fails with following error:

Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.2
09:07:00.437  Updating build integration targets...
09:07:00.451  Fetching analysis configuration settings...
09:07:01.239  Could not find a file on the SonarQube server. URL: https:///api/qualityprofiles/search?defaults=true
09:07:01.239  Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1

I tried following:

D:\Temp\tools\Scanner_MSBuild-2.2\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:myproj /n:myproj-full /v:1.0.0 /s:D:\Temp\SonarQube.Analysis.xml -Dsonar.buildbreaker.skip=true

But it threw error that -Dsonar.buildbreaker.skip=true is not recognised command. By default buildbreaker is set to false and I am not able to make it true via commandline. SonarQube version I am using is below 5.2.

How do I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using the Jenkins Begin Analysis and End Analysis build steps?

Comment: I was. It was also throwing error that "-Dsonar.buildbreaker.skip=true" is not recognised. Jenkins Begin Analysis plugin was automatically taking this parameter and was throwing error that Dsonar.buildbreaker.skip=true is not recognised. I think it is happening because Sonar version is below 5.2. Is there any way that through commandline, it can understand "Dsonar.buildbreaker.skip" option?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the 'Begin Analysis' and 'End Analysis' build steps, then configuring your server URL in SonarQube.Analysis.xml won't get you far (as you've learned).

Instead, you need to configure the location of your server at the global level as [described in the docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-Installation). Briefly:

- **Manage Jenkins > Configure System > SonarQube configuration**
- **Add SonarQube**
- fill in your server info.

Then double check that that server instance is selected in your build steps (if you have only one server configured, build steps will default to it). And analyze.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ann for the response. I have configured SonarQube in "Manage Jenkins" option as you have mentioned (and as mentioned in the link  also). I can see in the drop down of 'Begin Analysis' plugin the url. I have filled in other values also (project key , name , version). On triggering job, it throws me following error:

SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.2
04:39:10.325  Unrecognized command line argument: -Dsonar.buildbreaker.skip=true

Comment: I see that in 'advanced' option in SonarQube Configuration option in 'Manage Jenkins', as additional parameters "-Dsonar.buildbreaker.skip=true" is set and its taking this value from there. As it is set for other java based projects too, I cannot change it. How do I proceed with this now?

Comment: If I use Jenkins plugin to do start analysis then it throws error that Dsonar.buildbreaker.skip=true is not recognised. And if I try commandline way (using 'Windows powershell' plugin in the job), I get following error:
ould not find a file on the SonarQube server. URL: https://mysonar.dummy.com/prod/api/qualityprofiles/search?defaults=true
04:39:09.45  Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1